# Unable to install spacy english model in python 3.5

Tags: python-3.x, pip, spacy, rasa-nlu

I am doing the following:

```
root@ABZ-173:/home/abz# pip3 install en_core_web_md
Collecting en_core_web_md
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement en_core_web_md (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for en_core_web_md
You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

This used to work previously.
I do not want to link `spacy` to the model, `python -m spacy download en`.
Instead, I want to download it independently.
Also tried by various other means (by specifying version en_core_web_md==2.0.0, etc.). Unable to download.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

en_core_web_md doesn't exist as a package in its own right on pypi.org or Anaconda, so you can't just pip install it by name. However you can find download links for the model [on the GitHub page](https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models) and you can pip install directly from one of the download URLs, e.g.

```
pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_md-2.0.0/en_core_web_md-2.0.0.tar.gz
```

Note that when I tested that it did install spacy for me. So it might be easiest to just use spacy to download in the first place and change the linked model with `python -m spacy link` afterwards if necessary.

Comment: One small addition: The reason spaCy is installed is that the model package specifies the spaCy version it's compatible with in its `setup.py`. If spaCy is not installed yet, or if the version doesn't match, pip will install and/or update it, just like it would for any other dependency. Setting the `--no-deps` flag will turn this off (but also means that the user is responsible for making sure that the versions are compatible).

Answer (score 14):

I believe the space documentation covers all of the use cases you are after. Specifically looks like there are ~3 ways to download models.

- `python -m spacy download en` but that creates a link
- `python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm-2.0.0 --direct` this doesn't create a link
- `pip install https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz`

You can [include them in requirements](https://spacy.io/usage/models#models-download) with the following syntax

```
spacy>=2.0.0,<3.0.0
https://github.com/explosion/spacy-models/releases/download/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0/en_core_web_sm-2.0.0.tar.gz#en_core_web_sm
```

All of this was taken from the docs page [here](https://spacy.io/usage/models).

Comment: @Peter.k pip install your_file_name --user

Comment: I still think the best way would be the default: 

python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm